# Xamarin forms Android custom entry renderer applies to all entries after viewed once

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a custom entry renderer for Xamarin Forms Android like so

```cs
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomEntry), typeof(CustomEntryRenderer))]
namespace MyApp.Droid
{
    class CustomEntryRenderer : EntryRenderer
    {
        public CustomEntryRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control != null)
            {
                Control.Background = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My custom entry class is this

```cs
public class CustomEntry : Entry
{
}
```

The problem is that in the application, once a page containing the custom entry is viewed once, all other pages display no border on every entry no matter if that entry is a custom entry or not.  Entries are normal and contain borders until I view a page containing a custom entry

Comment: Can you add other code as well?may be create github repo and post the link for us to debug.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot post the whole project.  I added another custom entry that resets the border to normal.  It works until I use the first custom entry, then all subsequent do not show the border no matter what type.  Its like some kind of cache or something

Comment: Can you add the second custom entry code here if you don't mind?

Comment: Are you trying to set background color to white? Instead of null set it to Color.White

Comment: I tried your code, but could not reproduce your error

Comment: Yeah it's strange. It's something messed up in the project somewhere.  I couldn't spend any more time on it so I just made all entries custom rendered